# Syntactic Predicates + tree operator

Tags: java, antlr3

I have existing grammar with  Syntactic Predicates at function_call_expression rule. see the rule definition below :

```
function_call_expression
 :
  (atom_sub (DOT identifier_name)) => atom_sub (DOT identifier_name (LPAREN expression_list? RPAREN))+
  | atom_sub_call
    ->
      ^('functioncall' atom_sub_call)
  ;
```

I wanted to modify the grammar to introduce new tree nodes for each functionCall like below

```
atom_sub (DOT identifier_name (LPAREN expression_list? RPAREN))+ 
-> 
 ^ ( 'functioncall' atom_sub (DOT identifier_name (LPAREN expression_list? RPAREN))+ )
```

I am not sure how to do it if there are symantic predicates in rule alternative. please help me to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

The syntactic predicate plays no role in tree rewriting. Add your rewriting code just as if there was no predicate. The predictate is only used to guide the parser (it's like local backtracking).